# Is a runtime equality check of allocators bound to happen even if `is_always_equal` is true?

Tags: c++, allocator

When implementing an allocator aware container, some members require special handling with respect to the allocators.

For example (as I understand it): If the container is move assigned and

```
propagate_on_container_move_assignment^::value
```

is false, memory can still be "hijacked" iff both allocator compare equal.

The question is now, whether the equality check is actually required (or should be performed) if

```
is_always_equal::value
```

is true or not?

Rationale:

The standard library I'm using supports the `is_always_equal` trait property.
The move assignment operator of the `std::vector` implementation has the noexcept specification

```
noexcept(_alt::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value
    || _alt::is_always_equal::value)
```

and effectively has a call like

```
_move_it(std::forward<...>(rhs), 
    _alt::propagate_on_container_move_assignment{});
```

(with `_alt` being the allocator traits) where the `move_it` overload in case of non-propagating allocators looks like:

```
void _move_it(...&& rhs, std::false_type)
{
    if(_alloc() == rhs._alloc())
        // steal
    else
        // move data elements
}
```

with the `true_type` overload just stealing the memory.

Thus, we have a compile-time `noexcept` guarantee in case `is_always_true::value` is true.

The noexcept could then be violated in two ways:

1. `_alloc() == rhs._alloc()` throws.
2. `_alloc() != rhs._alloc()` returns false and an element move constructor throws.

(*Note: I'm aware of the fact that a throwing `operator==` as well as a non-equality in context of a `is_always_true` promise both are violating standard requirements.*)

Changing the above call to

```
_move_it(std::forward<...>(rhs), 
    std::disjunction<_alt::propagate_on_container_move_assignment, 
    _alt::is_always_equal>{});
```

however, should enforce `noexcept` because stealing/swapping the pointers actually can't throw and it would avoid a runtime-equality check (that might or might not be optimized out in case of stateless allocators).

Is there a specific reason to actually perform the equality check rather than circumvent it?

Comment: This is QoI, and any decent optimizer should be able to optimize out the comparison if it's just `return true;`. However, the proposed implementation won't work because POCMA means you'll move assign the allocator, but if !POCMA then move assignment need not be provided at all. That said, there is a justification for mandating a compile-time dispatch on `is_always_equal`, and that is allowing container move assignment to work with a non-MoveConstructible/MoveAssignable element type.

Comment: @T.C.: A pocma check with move assignment of the allocator happens before the `_move_it` call. The `_move_it` call just decides whether the data can be moved via stealing the pointer (which happens if pocma or if allocators are equal) or via moving the elements one by one into a new buffer (which happens if !pocma and allocators are not equal).